# Event handling onclick Body response in every object

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is a pattern game in which the user is supposed to find 1 missed picture from right side while the location is shown on left, then if the user guessed correctly they will go to the next level.

My problem is that, even though I clicked on correct picture, the popup for wrong choice is appearing after the first iteration.

I tried to define `body` as the initial child but still popup is displaying regardless of correct or wrong choice.

```js
var numberOfFaces = 5;
var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide");
var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

function generateFaces() {
  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfFaces; i++) {

    var createImg = document.createElement("IMG");
    var randPositionTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
    var randPositionleft = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
    createImg.setAttribute("src", "http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png");
    createImg.style.top = randPositionTop + "px";
    createImg.style.left = randPositionleft + "px";
    theLeftSide.appendChild(createImg);
  }
  var leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
  leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);
  theRightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages);

  theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick =
    function nextLevel(event) {
      event.stopPropagation;
      numberOfFaces += 5;
      alert("Next level!");

      while (theLeftSide.firstChild) {
        theLeftSide.removeChild(theLeftSide.firstChild);
      }
      generateFaces();
    }

  theBody.onclick =
    function gameOver() {
      theBody.onclick = null;
      theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = null;
      alert("Game Over!");
    };

}
```

```css
#leftSide {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  left: 50px;
}
#rightSide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 600px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  --border-left: solid 10px;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<body onload="generateFaces()">


  <h3>Matching Game</h3>
  <h5>Please choose missed smile !</h5>
  <div id="leftSide">
  </div>

  <div id="rightSide">
  </div>

  <script src="jsCode.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Please create a fiddle.

Comment: i dont know why but img is not loaded: https://jsfiddle.net/ychq5rkm/

Comment: There's a few things wrong here, but I think what's blocking you is that `event.stopPropagation` is a function, and should be called as such, like `event.stopPropagation()`. Also, when you use `theLeftSide.clone()` you are cloning the wrapping `div`, so you end up with two `div`s with the id "leftSide", which is invalid. Consider grabbing `theLeftSide.children` and cloning each.

Answer (score 0):

Updated your fiddle. Is this how you want it?

https://jsfiddle.net/ychq5rkm/12/

Specifically it uses `document.ready()` in the js instead of in the onload in the html. As was mentioned in the comments, you needed to actually call `event.stopPropegation()` because it was continuing up to the body each time and ending your game.

Comment: Thank you,yes.However, I'm still a bit confused about the purpose behind `document.ready()` instead of HTML as if game worked without this line after the program was changed to `event.stopPropagation()` .

Comment: The game didn't load in my browser on the fiddle with it in the html. It gave me function not found and would error. Not sure why. Running Chrome on OSX